# Yii Xupload: Forbidden error

Tags: yii, http-status-code-403, yii-xupload

I have tried everything the [xupload workflow tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/348/xupload-workflow) on yii tells us to do but i keep on getting a 'forbidden' error. I have tried to tweak the code in whatever way i could to no avail. Please advise. thanks

Comment: Post the code you already have. So we can see what you are going wrong

Comment: You have given too little info about problem. We cannot give you proper answer. Please post `XUploadController::accessRules()` where `XUploadController` is controller which handles file upload.

Answer (score 2):

Did you allow user access to action in accessControl() method?

Comment: thankyou for that. i had totally forgotten about it. i have rectified it and now it gives me 'internal server error'

Comment: thankyou very much arek and Oleg. rectified the problem and now it is working